# How can I get a distribution with the same mean and variance but different skewness?

Tags: statistics

1. I have the mean, variance and skewness of skew-normal distributed random numbers.
2. I have the mean variance and skewness of any distribution of random numbers.

How can I have same mean and variance but different skewness?

Answer (score 4):

I second daroczig's answer.

Also, if your data are all positive, a convenient skewed distribution to work with is the gamma. It has two parameters, shape and scale. The mean is shape*scale and the variance is shape*scale*scale.  So to match your mean and variance, set the scale of the gamma equal to the ratio of your variance to your mean. Then once you have the scale, set the shape to the mean divided by the scale.

Comment: That is definitely true: using gamma seems wiser and a lot simpler choice to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**If your question is "how is it possible" to get different skewness:**

As the first variable is a normal distribution, which is a symmetric one, while the other could be anything (e.g.: beta distribution), it is possible, that the second variable is assymetric, which makes the skewness differ of course, which measures the asymmetry of a variable.

**If your question is "how can it be done" to get different skewness:**

Generate an assymetric distribution with given mean and variance, so you will get a variable with the same mean and variance, but with different skewness. E.g. generate a beta distribution with [image] and [image] shapes in mind that the mean and variance of the generated variable will be around:

[image]

[image]

Of course any other assymetric distribution will work.

Comment: we have skew normal distribution with location=0, scale =1 and shape =0 then it is same as standard normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.but if we change the shape parameter say shape=5 then mean and variance also changes.how can we fix mean and variance with different values of shape parameter?

Comment: @Amber: I suppose skew normal distribution also have the corresponding formulas to compute mean and variance (to be obviuos and simple: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution). With those, as I suggested, you could manage to find the parameters you are interested in with given mean and variance. Well, three unknown parameter is bit harder to compute from 2 equations :) Better to use the beta or gamma distribution suggested by @John D. Cook.